# Sync Framework: Can I synchronise Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, microsoft-sync-framework

Does the sync framework allow me to synchronise (download only) the Store Procedures on a sql server 2008 server with the Stored procedures on the SQL Server 2008 client?

i.e. overwrite the SP on the client when the server SP's have been modified or new ones created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant do that, The Sync Framework is designed to sync data from server to a users pc and back again. While it can synchronize between servers, you are better off using SQL2008 replication engine, or a 3rd party API, such as Redgates SQLcompare, which you can operate programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Sync Framework is used to synchronize data not the database schema or the periphery.  Generally speaking, this is an application update issue.